# VB graphics from image file shows bigger than it's original size

Tags: vb.net, image, graphics, fromfile

I have this in vb.net :

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim output As New Bitmap(300, 300)
    Dim gfx As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(output)
    Sub refreshScreen() Handles Timer1.Tick
        gfx.DrawImage(Image.FromFile("wheel.png"), New Point(50, 50))
        gfx.FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue, 100, 100, 25, 25) 'Some other drawings on top
        PictureBox1.Image = output
    End Sub
End Class
```

The problem is that "wheel.png" shows bigger in the PictureBox1 than it's original resolution and is like scaled and blurred. How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the line :

```
gfx.DrawImage(Image.FromFile("wheel.png"), New Point(50, 50))
```

by :

```
gfx.DrawImage(Image.FromFile("wheel.png"), New Rectangle(0, 0, 225, 70))
```

A rectangle specify the size, so You will not worry about the weird scaling. You could even have you image in a variable object, and accessing this object .Height and .Width to fix the DrawImage issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check your image, the resolution and the image properties of the image of your PictureBox
And if you want draw at picture.